# In a gyroplane, how can the angle of attack of the rotor disk be calculated?

Tags: aerodynamics, rotary-wing

In a gyroplane, how can the angle of attack of the rotor disk be calculated as a function of the relevant variables?

Those 'relevant variables' are the rotor's angular velocity, the aircraft's airspeed, the blade chord and pitch, the rotor diameter, the slopes of the drag and lift at the relevant intervals of the blade profile and the air density...

Comment: Don't forget the attitude of the gyrocopter!

Comment: The attitude of the gyro's body has nothing to do with the AoA of the rotor tip-path plane, when the gyro's flying s/l, since that angle is determined only by the rotor's drag and lift.